# SELECT en PostgreSQL para 4 tablas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo 4 tablas de la siguiente manera:

```
-----------   |    -----------   |  -------------  |   ------------   
   caja       |      facturas    |   proveedores   |    productos
-----------   |    -----------   |  -------------  |   ------------
id            |    factura_id    |  proveedor_id   |   producto_id
fecha         |    proveedor_id  |  nombre         |   descripcion
monto         |    producto_id   |  direccion      |   precio
factura_id    |    monto         |                 |   unidad
descripcion   |    impuestos     |                 |
```

Lo que quiero obtener es: todos los movimientos de caja; y aquellos donde factura_id no es nulo, entonces tambien me muestre el nombre del proveedor y la descripción del producto.

Lo que intente es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT caja.id, caja.fecha, caja.monto, caja.descripcion, 
       proveedores.nombre, productos.descripcion
FROM caja, facturas, proveedores, productos
WHERE caja.factura_id = facturas.factura_id AND facturas.proveedor_id = 
      proveedores.proveedor_id AND factura.producto_id = 
      productos.producto_id
```

La consulta funciona salvo por el detalle de que solo me tira los movimientos de caja donde hay una factura_id, y yo tengo movimientos donde no hay facturas, y quisiera que también salieran en la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La parte fundamental de tu pregunta es *"todos los movimientos de caja"* por lo que podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.fecha, 
       c.monto, 
       c.descripcion, 
       p.nombre, 
       pr.descripcion
       FROM caja c
       LEFT JOIN facturas f
            ON f.factura_id = c.factura_id
       LEFT JOIN proveedores p
            ON f.proveedor_id = p.proveedor_id
       LEFT JOIN productos pr
            ON f.producto_id = pr.producto_id
```

Detalle:

- Lo fundamental aquí es que partimos de `caja` como table base, y luego usamos `LEFT JOIN` con el resto de las tabla, lo que nos asegura todas las filas de `caja` y las que coincidan del resto de las tablas.
- Estamos usando `JOINS` explícitos, tomalo como una buena práctica, además de indicar un alias a cada tabla que te hará la vida más fácil
- Obviamente aquellas filas de `caja`  que no tengan `factura_id` producirán `NULL`en las columnas `p.nombre` y `pr.descripcion`.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba de este modo, para dejarlo como un `JOIN EXPLÍCITO`:

```
SELECT  caja.id, caja.fecha, caja.monto, caja.descripcion, 
        proveedores.nombre, productos.descripcion
FROM facturas
JOIN caja ON facturas.factura_id = caja.factura_id
JOIN proveedores ON proveedores.proveedor_id = facturas.proveedor_id
JOIN productos ON productos.producto_id = facturas.producto_id
WHERE facturas.factura_id IS NOT NULL;
```

- Primero elegimos las columnas deseadas indicando su tabla origen
- hacemos 3 `JOINS` uno por cada tabla relacionada
- Hacemos uso de `IS NOT NULL` para filtrar los resultados de aquellos cuyo id de la factura sea distinto de nulo

En caso de que quieras seguir manteniendo tu consulta, debería bastar con agregar una condición `WHERE` de este modo para filtrar:

```
WHERE facturas.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No esta funcionando como deberia. De hecho me esta dando el mismo resultado que la consulta que hice yo; o sea, no esta mostrando los registros de caja que no tienen una factura relacionada, o sea, en los que en caja, el valor factura_id es NULL no me aparecen en la consulta, y lo que yo necesito es que si se vean los mismos. Si es que en caja hay una factura relacionada, entonces que muestre el nombre del proveedor y la descripcion del producto, pero si no hay una factura relacionada, entonces solo muestre el resto de los el resto de los campos...